# Can redis do hundreds of transactions per second on single key-value pair

Tags: database, database-design, redis, in-memory-database

I have an application, which works on API calls. On every API call I perform some task and charge for it(which can be sending mail or SMS or any such thing).

Currently I keep my users balance/credit data in MYSQL table in following form :

```
|user|balance|
|a   |1200   |
|b   |1200   |
|c   |1300   |
|d   |1400   |
|e   |1212   |
|f   |9000   |
|g   |8000   |
|h   |7000   |
```

But this is creating a problem when a single user hits thousands of APIs per minute. And on every API I update the user's balance and if there is not sufficient balance, I return some error.
When no of API hits is small, there is no issue but when it is large, updating the balance creates a lock on that row and other APIs have to wait to process.

I was thinking of moving this table to some cache or in-memory database so that I can fast this process.

Earlier I had Memcache in mind but it is volatile and so on searching, I read about Redis.
But I am confused, that my problem will be solved by this or not?
As for different keys, fetching data from Redis may be fast, as it is kept in memory/RAM only, but how will it work if there are thousands of update and search queries for same/single key.

Please share if you have any knowledge or experience regarding this or if anyone has an even better solution for my problem than Redis, please help.

Comment: It sounds like you're after the DECR command https://redis.io/commands/decr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes, Redis would accomplish what you're looking to do. It can [handle very high throughput](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks), [can be configured to be persistent](http://redis.io/topics/persistence), and you can [set it up in an HA manner with Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel). Having it handle your level of thousands of API calls a minute should be no problem at all.

That said, it's also not definitely necessary. If you're OK with having a few second lag in declaring to users when they're out of credits, I'd also recommend caching the number of API calls per box and just flushing to db (either Redis or MySQL) every few seconds that total amount of credits used/added per box during that time. Adding/subtracting those numbers should be idempotent, and just flushing every few seconds should resolve your main issue of not being able to handle unexpectedly large amounts of MySQL hits at random times.

So, you've got a few good options here. Pick whichever makes the most sense for your use case.

Answer (score -6):

The folks behind redis certainly claim those sort of speeds.  But, redis is also 'volatile' so if that was what caused you to back away from memcache, what's different about redis?  It also has no persistence layer.

You can look for an in-memory database with MVCC (optimistic concurrency model) to avoid read/write/delete tasks blocking readers.  You can mitigate the volatility issue by using NVDIMM (if your server is modern enough and the IMDB you choose supports the ability to recover a database in NVDIMM), or replication.

Comment: It can reach 200k+ ops per second on a regular laptop processor. It **has** a persistence layer, too. And a high-availability module (called Sentinel).

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I was told by a high level contact at RedisLabs that there was no persistence.  I don't have any first hand experience with redis.

Comment: Redis even has **two** mechanisms for persistence: (1) snapshotting, and (2) append-only files. Both mechanisms can be used simultaneously if you wish.

Comment: @StevenGraves of course Redis is persistent - I would really want to know who that contact from Redis Labs is so I can correct his/her mistake.

Comment: I'm not going to "out" the fellow on a public forum. I'll take responsibility, and apologize, for accepting (and repeating) his information and not doing my own independent research.

Comment: Granted - I'd still appreciate your assistance on the matter via a private communication channel such as email - I'm available via itamar@redislabs.com